# Button Click not triggering jQuery(Ajax) function to update page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a website where I display student info. I want to add few text fields on the website and update those fields asynchronously using jQuery(Ajax) on Button click. I believe I have all the requirements in place but the data is still not updated.

Am I missing something here? Clicking buttons does nothing.

Here is my Code -

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Student.Models;    

namespace Student.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {           
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Student");
        }  

        [HttpPost()]    
        public ActionResult DisplayStudentName(string id)
        {
            StudentDataContext db = new StudentDataContext();
            var StudentName = (from p in db.vwStudent.Where(a => a.StudentId == id)
                             group p by p.StudentName into g
                             select g.Key).FirstOrDefault();

            ViewData["StudentName"] = StudentName;

            return View("Student");

        }

        [HttpPost()]
        public ActionResult DisplayStudentStatus(int? id, string flg)
        {
            AccountDataContext db = new AccountDataContext();
            var StudentStatus = (from p in db.vwStudent.Where(a => a.StudentId == id && a.LastFlag == flg)
                             group p by p.Status into g
                             select g.Key).FirstOrDefault();

            ViewData["StudentStatus "] = StudentStatus;

            return View("Student");

        }

    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
    $("#Button1").click(function() {
        var link = '<%= Url.Action("DisplayStudentName", "Student")';
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            data: "{id: '<%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] %>'}",
            dataType: "html",
            success: Success,
            error: Fail
        });
    });

    $("#Button2").click(function() {
        var link = '<%= Url.Action("DisplayStudentStatus", "Student")';
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            data: "{id: '<%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] %>' , 
                    flg: '<%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["flg"] %>'}",
            dataType: "html",
            success: Success,
            error: Fail
        });
    });

function Success(){
alert("Success");
}

function Fail(){
alert("Fail");
}
```

View:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
        Student Form
    </asp:Content>

    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <form id="form1" method="get" runat="server">

Student ID:<input type="text" name="id" id="StudentId" value="<%=HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"]%>" /><br />

Student Name:<input type="text" name="StudentName" id="StudentName" value="<%=ViewData["StudentName"]%>"/>
<div id="Btn1"><input type="button" value="Display Student Name" name="Btn1" id="Button1" />
</div>

Student Status:<input type="text" name="StudentStatus" id="StudentStatus" value="<%=HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["StudentStatus"]%>" />       
<div id="Btn2"><input type="button" value="Display Profit Center" name="Btn2" id="Button2" />
</div>

</div>         
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want something to happen when the button's onClick fires, right? I think you need an onClick attribute for that.

Comment: Have you checked you're not getting a Javascript error somewhere. For example, using Chrome have you had a look at the Console log? @BobHorn the `$("#Button1").click` contains the handler to run the script when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code that I see:

- You should not wrap the `data` parameters into single quotes.
- Your success and error parameters should not be strings. They should be functions
- You should never hardcode urls in an ASP.NET MVC application. You should always use url helpers when dealing with urls

So:

```
$("#Button1").click(function() {
    var link = '<%= Url.Action("DisplayStudentName", "Student")';
    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        data: { id: '<%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] %>' },
        success: Success,
        error: Fail
    });
});

$("#Button2").click(function() {

    var link = '<%= Url.Action("DisplayStudentStatus", "Student")';
    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        data: {
            id: '<%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] %>' , 
            flg: '<%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["flg"] %>' 
        },
        success: Success,
        error: Fail
    });
});
```

where obviously you must have declared the 2 functions used:

```
function Success(data) {
    // ...
}

function Fail() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I updated my jQuery as per your suggestions, but still nothing happens, Feels like my jQuery is not even triggered when I click "Display Student Name" button. Also, what should I have in my Success and Fail functions? is it ok if I just show a message? I have updated my code above.

Comment: What happens if you put an alert inside the click callback? Do you have jQuery referenced in your view? What you will do in the Success and Fail functions will entirely depend on what you are trying to achieve. You could define them as anonymous functions as well. Try debugging your code. Use javascript debugging tools such as FireBug which will help you very much.

Comment: I dont see the alert "Success" or "Fail". I have referenced jQuery in my Site.Master: <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/StudentDetails.js"></script>
I will see if I can get permission to download FireBug here at work. I want to display the Student Name based on Student Id entered once I click "Display Student Name" Button and same for Student Status. Wouldnt "Button1" and "Button2" click functions take care of this? or would I need to do it in "Success" and "Fail" functions instead?

Comment: `/Scripts/StudentDetails.js` is **not** jQuery. I really recommend you reading some getting started tutorials about jQuery as you seem to be lacking some very fundamental concepts: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Comment: I corrected the reference to:
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

I am referencing googles version of jQuery. I did read that document earlier. I understand the basics, its just that I dont know what I am missing in my code.

Comment: For this you will have to debug your code. Use a poor-man debugging with alerts if your system administrator in the company has been in a coma for the last 5 years and forbids you from installing FireBug, or if he hasn't, well, then install and use FireBug.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the help. Will try installing FireBug. One thing I want to clear is, Wouldnt "Button1" and "Button2" click functions take care of displaying respective texts? or do I need to do it in "Success" and "Fail" functions instead?

Comment: Depends on where is this text coming from. From what I can see your controller actions return views. Is it this markup that you want to display? If so then you should do it in the Success handler because it is only inside this handler that you have access to the results of the AJAX call.

Comment: The Text is coming from DB, after executing the Controller Actions. Student ID is entered, "Display Studnet Name" button is clicked and jQuery is executed using Ajax to update the student name text box asynchronously(without refreshing the page). Yes, I am returning views as I didnt know of any other available solutions. Let me know if I am on the right path, or need to revise my approach. There will  be many fields on the view which would need to be updated asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

need to mention post in ur ajax parameters

```
    $.ajax({
            url: link,
            type: 'post',
```

Also you have mentioned json as the datatype in your ajax function but your action is returning text/html.

Make these 2 changes and if it doesnt work then check fiddler to see what response you are getting from the server.

If you are getting a valid response then check your success function to see if you are doin things right.

If you want to support get and post scenarios on your action then change the attribute on your action to

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
```